# How do I add keyword arguments to a derived class's constructor in Python?

Tags: python, constructor, keyword-argument

I want to add keyword arguments to a derived class, but can't figure out how to go about it. Trying the obvious

```
class ClassA(some.package.Class):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ClassB(ClassA): 
    def __init__(self, *args, a='A', b='B', c='C', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
```

fails because I can't list parameters like that for `ClassB`'s `__init__`. And

```
class ClassB(ClassA):   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
```

of course doesn't work because the new keywords aren't specified.

How do I add keyword arguments to the `__init__` for a derived class?

Comment: Did you try removing them before calling the superclass?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Is that the Pythonic approach (is there no other way?)? If so that's probably the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Usually we write our code like this. `class Derived(Base):
    def meth (self):
        super(Derived, self).meth()
` Any specific reason for not following this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):            
        self.a = kwargs.pop('a', 'A')
        self.b = kwargs.pop('b', 'B')
        self.c = kwargs.pop('c', 'C')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Effectively you add the keyword arguments `a`, `b` and `c` to `ClassB`, while passing on other keyword arguments to `ClassA`.

Comment: Should't the `pop`s go first because those are keywords the derived class is not expecting?

Comment: @erewok Yup, I messed that up on my initial edit oops.

Comment: And so there's *really* no way to get the new keyword arguments into the method signature?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Rawing's answer shows a way to do it.

Comment: @aknuds1: There seems to be a dispute about whether those are keyword arguments. It [looks like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472803/656912) they're just positional arguments (with defaults).

Comment: `**kwargs` just receives keyword arguments which don't correspond to any formal parameters. That's the definition. So it depends on whether you want formal parameters or not. So it seems that according to Python's definition, keyword arguments refer to named arguments at invocation time. I.e., you can treat formal parameters as *either* positional or keyword arguments.

Comment: @aknuds1: Yes, sorry. It has the side effect of making them formal parameters (and thus positional) *also*; they're still technically keyword arguments, just not (confusingly) ones that show up in `kwargs` — right?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius It's not really confusing that they're not in kwargs, since the latter contains keyword arguments that are not formal parameters. Same thing with args, those are positional parameters not among the formal ones.

Comment: @aknuds1: I just meant the terminology was confusing (to me). I see what's going on (I think).

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Hopefully my explanation makes it clear how these things work. Just consider `*args` and `**kwargs` bags for non-formalized ("extra") arguments.

Comment: @aknuds1: Now I'm told (see comments below) they are *not keyword arguments*. See comments on [Haleemur Ali's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472803/656912). Whether they are or aren't is critical to deciding what the correct answer here is. Can you join the discussion there and clarify?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius I think I've clarified what a keyword argument is in my comments to his answer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `super(ClassB, self)` not `super(ClassA, self)` on the last line?

Answer (score 4):

All you need do is rearrange the arguments.

```
def __init__(self, a='A', b='B', c='C', *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: This has different effect.

Comment: @OlehPrypin: How does the effect differ from the solutions below? It seems to do what I want, but maybe I didn't ask clearly.

Comment: The difference is, of course, the order of the arguments. Assuming you call `ClassB(5)`, my solution would be equivalent to `ClassB(a=5)`, while the other solutions would be kind of like `ClassB(args=[5])`.

Comment: if the user initiates an object of class ClassB like this: `b = ClassB('hello')` this will assign `'hello'` to the instance attribute `a`, and not treat it as a positional argument. This doesn't solve the OP's problem of adding new key word only arguments to the subclass.

Comment: So if `ClassA`'s `__init__` has `(x, y, z, p='P')` how would I get a call to `ClassB(...)` to set `x`, `y`, or `z`? I think seems to work for me only because `ClassA`'s base (`matplotlib.figure.Figure`) takes only keyword arguments.

Comment: @HaleemurAli: Can you explain what you mean by "ill assign ... to the instance attribute"?

Comment: sure, I can post the side effects of the above method signature in an answer, comments doesn't allow for proper code formatting to do that, give me a minute.

Answer (score 2):

#### Effect of `def __init__(self, a='A', b='B', c='C', *args, **kwargs):`

Modifying the OP's code with the child class's constructor having the above signature:

```
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class ClassA(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, a='A', b='B', c='C', *args, **kwargs):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


A = ClassA('hello', 'world', myname='hal',myemail='hal@hal.hal')
B = ClassB('hello', 'world', myname='hal', myemail='hal@hal.hal')

print("CLASS A:", A.__dict__)
print("CLASS B:", B.__dict__)
# yields the following:
CLASS A: {'args': ('hello', 'world'), 'myname': 'hal', 'myemail': 'hal@hal.hal'}
CLASS B: {'args': (), 'myname': 'hal', 'a': 'hello', 'myemail': 'hal@hal.hal', 'c': 'C', 'b': 'world'}
```

The code will not throw an exception, however, a, b & c are now positionally the first 3  arguments passed to the method (ignoring `self`) , as seen from the two object's dicts.

Accessing the attributes a, b & c shows this *other effect*

```
>>> B.a # expect to see 'A'
'hello'
>>> B.b # similarly
'world'
>>> B.c # but this retails the default value
'C'
```

AFAIK, you can't add new keyword only arguments to the method signature. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

However, both @aknuds1 and @Oleh Prypin provided solutions that effectively add new keyword arguments to the child class. Oleh's solution is a bit more clever, but I find aknuds1's version easier to understand.

- pop elements from the `kwargs` dict, coalesced to the default value
- assign to the instance attribute using `setattr`
- call parent constructor with args, kwargs

Comment: So [Rawing's approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472393/656912) does not in fact add keyword arguments: it adds positional arguments (with defaults)?

Comment: Yes, Rawing's approach will add positional arguments with default values. `Key word only` argument support has been added to python 3+, and it works as you expected, i.e. `def __init__(self, *args, a='A', b='B', c='C', **kwargs):` is valid syntax and does just that.

Comment: So that puts me in a bit of a bind regarding acceptance: Rawing's answer is the best for my purposes, and in general, I think, given the desire to have as much information as possible in the signature (and that there's no requirement — that I know of — for subclass constructors to preserve the order of those in their parent classes); BUT your answer provides the best explanation of his answer. Suggestions?

Comment: The answers posted by aknuds1 or Oleh Prypin answer your question as you posed it (adding key word argument to a method that overrides the parent). Rawing's approach, though helpful to you, doesn't accurately answer the stated question. And my post isn't so much an answer to your question as an explanation of what Rawing's code actually accomplishes.

Comment: But as aknuds1 points out, Rawing's does answer the question since it does indeed add keyword arguments. And it has the added advantage of putting them in the signature. Is that not correct?

Comment: No, that's not correct. While Rawing's proposed method is perfectly valid way to add arguments, it **does not** add key word arguments. It adds positional arguments, enabling statements such as this `B = ClassB('hello', 'world')` which is equivalent to `B = ClassB(a='hello', b='world')`

Comment: So aknuds1 comments are wrong, right? I had though that (as I ask above) Rawing's approach adds positional arguments (with defaults); but aknuds1's seem to say otherwise: those arguments are indeed keyword arguments. I don't know who is right.

Comment: try it yourself, if you can pass in an argument without specifying its name, its not a key word argument.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius If you read [Python's glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html), you'll see that a keyword argument is *an argument preceded by an identifier (e.g. name=) in a function call or passed as a value in a dictionary preceded by \*\**

Comment: Therefore, whether an argument is a keyword argument or not is determined by whether it is named when the function in question is called.

Comment: @aknuds1: I'm the innocent bystander. I think you mean to address HaleemurAli.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Well, it's directed at both of you.

Comment: @aknuds1, thanks for the clarification. I learned something new today :)

Comment: @aknuds1: So to conclude: "...as aknuds1 points out, Rawing's *does* answer the question since it does indeed add keyword arguments. And it has the added advantage of putting them in the signature."

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Well, according to Python's definition it doesn't really matter if arguments in the signature have default values or not (although such arguments *can* be positional). But it's a simpler way to ensure that e.g. argument `a` goes to ClassB and not ClassA. My alternative works too, it only depends on what you're after.

Comment: @aknuds1: Yeah, I think I'm going to have to go with what the general SO reader is thinking when he comes across this question ([your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472354/656912)) even though for me (and in in the strict technical sense) [Rawing's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472393/656912) is more useful (and [Haleemur Ali's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27472803/656912) provides a more complete version of it).

Answer (score 0):

Use Python 3.x, which makes keyword-only arguments valid.

Or use this workaround...

```
class ClassB(ClassA):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg, default in [('a', 'A'), ('b', 'B'), ('c', 'C')]:
            setattr(self, arg, kwargs.pop(arg, default))
        super(ClassA, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: So there's no way to list them in the signature — all I can say is `**kwargs`?

Comment: There **was** no way to list them in the signature in old versions of Python.

Comment: Let's not make this about 2 vs. 3.